# C# Access base class variables/functions from abstract class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract

Maybe its not possible or i am mixing something up, but its breaking my head.

Let's say, we got an abstract class A and a class B based of A. Is it possible for A to access variables/functions from B?

Example:

```
 abstract class A
 {
    public bool activeA = false;

    public bool getState()
    {
        return test; // The variable from class B
    }
 }

 class B : A
 {
    public bool test = true;

    public void isActive()
    {
         return base.getState(); // So this should return true because getState() should access the variable test^^
    }

 }
```

Comment: Well... abstract class can't be instantiable, so it can't access a variable existing in `class B`. See: [abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve with this? There may be a better approach, but without more information about the problem I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: They seem so entwined it's not clear why you wouldn't just have an `AB` class. Perhaps give us a more *concrete* example?

Comment: What if there is a subclass of `A` that doesn't have a `test` field? It cannot possibly work. Maybe you want to move `getState()` to `B`, or even make it abstract so that `B` can implement it using its own specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `A` doesn't know anything about `B` or potentially `C..Z`.

If `test` would be on `A`, then both `A` and `B` could access it. Or you could create an interface that's implemented by `B` and that `A` knows about and pass `B` as a parameter to `A`.

This could look like this:

```
interface IB
{
    bool Test { get; }
}

abstract class A
{
   public bool activeA = false;

   public bool getState(IB arg)
   {
       return arg.Test;
   }
}

class B : A, IB
{
   public bool Test => true;

   public bool isActive()
   {
         return base.getState(this); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: You're not serious, are you? ;-) Your solution would be technically possible, but it is not really a vialble solution because it is pretty hard to comprehend.

Comment: @Valvastino Seeing that it's marked as an answer, I hope it helped the original question asker. Hard to comprehend depends on your use case. If you really encounter a scenario like this, this could be an acceptable solution. What would you suggest?

Comment: Well, I posted an answer to the original question below. A simple solution is using the abstract base class as abstract. Meaning: declaring an abstract method/property which must be implemented in deriving classes. Less code and "circular" dependencies to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. The abstract class knows nothing about the classes which inherit from it, so it can't use their properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because class A doesn't know that B exists.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned: it is not generally possible to access the field test of class B from class A.

But you could declare your method getState() as abstract:

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract bool getState();

    void AccessState()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("state: {0}", getState());
    }
}
```

All classes derving from A must implement the method getState (or be abstract themselves):

```
class B : A
{
    bool test = true;
    public override bool getState()
    {
        return test;
    }
}
```

This way you enforce all non abstract inheritors of class A to provide an implementation of all abstract methods and properties. You define a contract on which class A can rely on. This way you can call getState() in class A and indirectly get the value of the field test from class B.